# Element is possible 'null'

Tags: typescript

I do get the typescript error `'node' is possibly 'null'` for this function:

```
import { MatcherFunction } from '@testing-library/react'

type Query = (f: MatcherFunction) => HTMLElement

export const withMarkup = (query: Query) => (text: string) => {
  const hasText = (node: Element) => node.textContent === text
  return query((_, node) => {
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      (child) => !hasText(child)
    )
    return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText
  })
}
```

I would like to get some explanation how to handle this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatcherFunction` is typed as:

```
(content: string, element: Element | null) => boolean
```

Which means that when you do:

```
return query((_, node) => {
  //...
})
```

`node` is of type `Element | null`. And you can't do `node.children` if `node` might be `null`, since that would cause a runtime crash.

---

To fix it you simply have to first check for `null`.

```
import { MatcherFunction } from '@testing-library/react'

type Query = (f: MatcherFunction) => HTMLElement

export const withMarkup = (query: Query) => (text: string) => {
  const hasText = (node: Element) => node.textContent === text
  return query((_, node) => {
    if (!node) return false
    // Added this line
    
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      (child) => !hasText(child)
    )
    return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText
  })
}
```

Now `node.children` will only be executed if `node` is *not* `null`, and is, therefore, never going to crash at runtime.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQIYwMYAsCmUBiArgHYYzATFwC+cAZlBCHAOQACMOAzucQOYBaADbAARlFRQAngHooOVGRYAoZTClgccAIqE8UuAF44ACjoAuFOmx4ipcpQCURgHxwAEgBVkAGQCiQjggOMQwqjgAHpCwcBiUPHAA7sAwWGhQANaEYEamAI560pa6+s6GbiacETCWPFDA-GVuCMpwsfHwWKhcnpHwxibEEAAmOJYBQSEwTXBDowB0VTAAwpScoUaGxkutcPIwhFBUBfomJgD6ADSzIzgzLW1twHSmAIRzd3s4B0f0qEJcHC7NrA9rEBLYYBCYbyYgAETW7lQADccL1qrkAIJQCRSeYMJiDW7zSHQ2GOeY4VHSEygtomUnDGavLo9PoMrBQpmgxyg-aHKis9EwImjZwAMnFsU5ZJCCNCSNRwt21F51CAA)